# Debian - How to find out if a package is multiarchified? Dependency changes as bug report

Tags: debian, wine, bugs

I'm using Debian Wheezy 64bit and wine is only existing in a 32bit version. So I added multiarch support. But when I want to install winetricks it's dependencies are

`depends on wine | wine-unstable`

and not

`depends on wine | wine-unstable | wine:i386`

So, aptitude suggests to install the dummy 64bit package or to not install winetricks... which doesn't make a lot of sense :)

So, I wonder if I have to report a bug because winetricks' dependencies are wrong. For me it seems like that, but I would expect that bug report already to be written.

How do I find out if a package has already been multiarchified? Will this issue be solved by only adding the `| wine:i386` in the package informations? Shall I write a bug report in such cases?

Comment: And what about installing winetricks:i386?

Comment: @enedil: I thought about ... starting a facepalm, but that package isn't existing.

Comment: Why do you think wine only exists in a 32 bit version?

Comment: @FaheemMitha "This is the wine64-bin helper package, which does not provide wine itself, but instead exists solely to provide the following information about enabling multiarch on your system in order to be able to install and run the 32-bit wine packages."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `winetricks` - multi-arch works in a different way as you think (I suggest (re-)reading the first sections of [Debian's Multiarch-HOWTO](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)).

You actually need to install the `wine:amd64`-package instead of the `wine:i386`-package. The wheezy wine package depends on `wine-bin | wine64-bin`. The first is resolved by the `wine-bin:i386` package as it has a `Multi-Arch: foreign` field in its control file. You can show its entries for example using `apt-cache show wine-bin`.

In newer Debian system, the `wine:amd64` package depends on  `wine64 | wine32`. The latter is resolved by the `wine32:i386` package.

Comment: Sorry, but the `wine:amd64` collides with `wine:i386` (I expect you've meant `wine:i386` instead of `wine32`, which isn't existing on my machine.)

Comment: @PythoNic Sorry, I fixed my answer. My original answer was only valid for Debian testing/unstable.

Answer (score 0):

One part of my question is a misunderstanding:

Although there is a 64bit dummy package `wine64-bin` this does not mean that `wine:amd64` is also such a package. My manual installation of the package `wine:i386` was apparantly not a clever move, but is also based on this misconception.

This is not the last word to say, because it doesn't explain the need for a 64bit version of the `wine` package while everything else is 32bit...